# How to pass info to View from Index in this scenario - MVC3

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

I have written following code:

```
public ActionResult Index()
        {                            
            var folders = Directory.GetDirectories(Server.MapPath("~/Content/themes/base/songs"));

            foreach (var folder in folders)
            {
                var movieName = new DirectoryInfo(folder).Name;
                string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(folder);
                string img = string.Empty;
                List<string> song = new List<string>();
                foreach (var file in files)
                {
                    if (Path.GetExtension(file) == ".jpg" ||
                        Path.GetExtension(file) == ".png")
                    {
                        img = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Content/themes/base/songs"), file);
                    }
                    else 
                    {
                        song.Add(Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Content/themes/base/songs"), file));
                    }
                }
            }
            return View();
        }
```

What i am trying to do is pass 20 movie names with movie images and each movie has about 4 or 5 songs that should display under it. I have figured out how to capture all this info above but i am not sure how to pass it into view to Display. Can someone please help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add some class to your application i guess. For example Movie and MovieSong and your Movie class should be has something like IList Images. Then you can pass your movies to your view easily.

I'm not sure whether this code working or not but you can try something like this:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{   
    var movies = new List<Movie>();

    var songsPath = Server.MapPath("~/Content/themes/base/songs");
    var folders = Directory.GetDirectories(songsPath);

    foreach (var folder in folders)
    {
        Movie movie = new Movie();
        movie.MovieName = new DirectoryInfo(folder).Name

        string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(folder);

        foreach (var file in files)
        {
            if (Path.GetExtension(file) == ".jpg" ||
                Path.GetExtension(file) == ".png")
            {
                movie.Images.Add(Path.Combine(songsPath, file));
            }
            else 
            {
                movie.Songs.Add(Path.Combine(songsPath, file));
            }
        }

        movies.add(movie);
    }
    return View(movies);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should populate a model object... and pass it in the return line:

```
var theModel = new MyModel();
...
//All the loading model info

return View(theModel)
```

In your View, you need to set a line in the top as follow:

```
@model YourProject.MyModel
```

Then, you do the looping throught the `@Model` object.

Answer (score 0):

**Q1. i am not sure how to pass it into view to Display**

A. You need to use View Model for this, below is a ViewModel that I have prepared for this.

```
public class Movie
{
    public string Name;
    public string ImagePath;
    ....
    ....
    //Add more as per your requirement
}
```

Push all the data you have into this Model prepared.

**Q2. What i am trying to do is pass 20 movie names with movie images and each movie has about 4 or 5 songs that should display under it**

A. Now as what you have is a collection of movies you will need to pass a list of this Movie class to the Model.

```
public ActionResult Index()
{   
    var movies = new List<Movie>();

    // populate the data

    return View(movies);
}
```

**Display it in View**

```
@model ProjectName.Models.List<Movies>

@foreach(var item in Model)
{
    <h1>Movie Name : </h1> @item.Name
    ....
    .... //etc etc
}
```

Hope this helps.